# Filter time difference in two date fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch, and I have data that have two fields time and received_time. I want to make sure that all records matching the query have the difference within a threshold. How do I achieve that effectively? The official documentation only talks about "now" or literal values. Thanks in advance.

Edit: if it matters, I need both a minimum value and a maximum value. Thanks.